# Angular : CORS error persists with proxy.conf.json

Tags: angular, cors, angular-httpclient

I have followed a few tutorials to solve my CORS errors but cannot solve it.

I have an extremely simple server that responds to `get 127.0.0.1:8080/hello` with the string `hello there` for testing purposes.

Obviously, with no config nor proxy, the request gets a CORS error and cannot proceed.

However, I cannot solve my problem with the proxy either because I am not using it properly or because there is a mistake I did that I cannot find. This is the proxy.conf.json :

```
{
  "/hello": {
    "target": "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

and this is the serve instruction : `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"`

I have also made absolutely sure that the file is called correctly by inserting errors that prevent compilation and tested the server with postman.

Here is the line of code that calls the server :

```
this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello').subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Note : I am using Angular 10.1.7 and - if possible - I would like to not change anything on the server as I will not always have access to the server for future issues

Comment: I don't think you need to add the 'pathRewrite' in your situation as it would rdirect to an url without the '/hello' fragment

Comment: good point, I did not get to that issue yet

Answer (score 0):

turns out the typescript code was the issue :

the proxy was correct but it was not used at all, the "good" code is as follows :

```
this.http.get('/hello').subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

by calling the entire url at once, the proxy is ignored but by calling the '/hello' the proxy can do the redirection

Note : the proxy will not work on a prod environment, this will have to be done on a .htaccess or the equivalent.